# How do I make mezzanine user email non-updatable?

Tags: python, django, django-models, mezzanine

I have created my first mezzanine app and would like my users to NOT be able to update their username nor their email after registration.

I have read through the user profile customization docs(http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html#profiles) and they don't describe how to perform this customization.

Customizing the userprofile with

### settings.py

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "myapp.MyProfile"
```

Can only add fields.

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py >>

```
ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_EXCLUDE_FIELDS = (
    "username",
    "email",
)
```

if it effects the first registration page maybe u will have to create your own registration page(It is easy)

Comment: You are right. It effects the registration page. I don't believe a new registration page will fix this unless I am mistaken. A new registration page with a new form could fix this issue if there are no other configuration methods of solving this then that would be a last resort.

Comment: If it is ok please press up arrow on may answer (:

Comment: I think I am still looking for the "right" answer if there is a way to handle this properly without rewriting the registration page.

Comment: There is no other clean way. Mezzanine gives no configuration about this. Maybe if u request this on here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mezzanine-users they may add this feature to next releases.

The another way is changing the source or monkey patching. But i don't suggest this, I've made this so many times before , it is very dirty solution and believe me it causes so many new problems on version change...